# TF400618 when migrating scrum 2.2 to scrum 3.0

Tags: migration, tfs-process-template

Our TFS 2012 team project was migrated to a new TFS2013 server with all data.

When I now try to activate the new "Portfolio Backlog" feature the following error is presented:

> [Error] TF400618: The reporting type of field
>   'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate' in work item type 'Feature'
>   conflicts with the reporting type of the existing field

In Scrum 2.2 the type definitions of SharedStep and TestCase have this field definition

```
 <FIELD name="State Change Date" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate" type="DateTime">
        <WHENCHANGED field="System.State">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </WHENCHANGED>
        <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
          <READONLY />
        </WHENNOTCHANGED>
      </FIELD>
```

In the Scrum 3.0 additional the Feature has these field.

In the MSDN under [TF400618: The reporting type of field '{0}' in work item type '{1}' conflicts with the reporting type of the existing field.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh913787.aspx)
I'm not understanding what I need to do to resolve the issue with the feature field.

Do I need to manually alter the scrum 2.2 process template with the feature work item type , publish the changed process template into the team project and than activate the "Portfolio Backlog"?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've modified your process template, TFS can't automatically install the new updates to it.  Here's guidance on how to update it manually: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194972(v=vs.120).aspx

I recommend that you instead script your process template changes in a batch file so that when new versions come out, you can easily repeat your changes in the new template rather than going through the 12-step manual process above.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to configure Features after performing all the steps as mentioned in :[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194972(v=vs.120).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194972%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

So I updated the Feature.xml such that the "State Change Date" FIELD name as a reportable option set to "dimentions"
After this change I updated the the default template to the one I had customized and was able to configure Features.
Here is how the updated code in Feature.xml looks:

```
<FIELD name="State Change Date" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension" >
```

Comment: i will give it a try on monday